# How to notify the admin if the items(Multiple items) are going to expire in days later-Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, cron, schedule, laravel-mail

There are many items in the Items table and there is an expired date column in the items table. I just want to get a push notification every day before each items going expire one date before (Expire dates are different to each other and can have one expire date to multuple items). im new to laravel. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### This can be simply done with [Laravel task scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling)

1. You need to create a [custom artisan command](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#generating-commands) like

   ```php
   php artisan make:command SendItemExpiryEmailsToAdmin
   ```

---

2. Under `App\Console\Commands` You will find a class `SendItemExpiryEmailsToAdmin` should be created.

   i) First you need to define the signature of the command which will be used to call from the command line.

   ```php
   protected $signature = 'email:send-item-expiry-email-to-admin';
   ```

   ii) Inside the `handle()` of the same class, write your logic. A sample logic is given below. You will need to create a [Mailable class](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail#writing-mailables) to send the mail.

   ```php
   public function handle() {
       // To fetch all the items ids which are going to expired today.
       $itemsIds = Items::whereBetween('expired',
               [Carbon::now()->setTime(0,0)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
               Carbon::now()->setTime(23,59,59)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')])
            ->pluck('id')
            ->toArray();
       $itemsIds = implode(" ", $itemsIds);
       Mail::queue(new ItemsExpiryEmail($itemsIds));
       // If you are not using queue, just replace `queue` with `send` in above line
   }
   ```

---

3. [Mailable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail#writing-mailables) to send the mail.

   i) Run the following command to create a mailable

   ```php
   php artisan make:mail ItemsExpiryEmail
   ```

   ii) In the mailable, write your code. A sample code is given below, you can use `$this->itemIds` in the mail view as it is a public variable.

   ```
   class ItemsExpiryEmail extends Mailable
   {
       use Queueable, SerializesModels; // don't forget to import these.
       public $itemIds;

       public function __construct($itemIds)
       {
           $this->itemIds = $itemIds;
       }

       public function build()
       {
           return $this->view('emails.orders.shipped');
           return $this->to('test@example.com', 'Admin')
               ->subject('Subject of the mail')
               ->view('emails.adminNotification'); // adminNotification will be the view to be sent out as email body
       }
   }
   ```

---

4. This command needs to be executed daily using the [Cornjob](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling).

Try this, I'm sure this will help. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Can you help me to with this database notifications

Comment: Sorry, @Helaka I didn't get you. What kind of help do you need?

Comment: I just need to send notifications as facebook notifcations. Can you help me with this

Comment: Are you talking about the mobile notifications?

Comment: @SatendraRawat I think OP is expecting some sort of socket based message/notification delivery system

Comment: @satendra rawat. Can you help me how to set the mail able class

Comment: Hey @Helaka, I've updated my answer above, let me know if that helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much..!! It works can you help me with database notifications also.

Comment: What kind of notifications?

Answer (score 0):

You can create Task scheduler in Laravel. you can get more info from it's doc here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling

1) you get create login in the scheduling code like. get the all the items which is expiring tomorrow, And send the detail of items to the admin email.

if you have some knowledge in user define artisan command you can also implement  scheduling-artisan-commands https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#scheduling-artisan-commands.